# Wordpress - Display latest 10 galleries

Tags: wordpress, gallery, image-gallery

I want to create a custom page that will display let's say 20 latest galleries / page - but only the first image from the gallery, not all of them. something like this: http://www.autoblog.it/gallerie/

I've done this:

```
<?php
 $args = array(
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'posts_per_page' => 10,
'post_parent' => $postid,
'numberposts' => 1,
'paged' => $paged,
);
 $attachments = get_posts($args);
if ($attachments) {
foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
echo the_attachment_link($attachment->ID, false, false, true )
echo get_the_title();   }
}?>
```

it works but what it does is to display latest 10 images, not latest 10 galleries, so first image from each gallery.

Please help

Thank you

Comment: ¿How are identified the different galleries?

Answer (score 2):

1. Create galleries page
2. Retrieve all posts who have gallery attached (add them to a Gallery category for example)
3. In the page, just retrieve all the posts inside gallery category:

   ```
   $args = array(
   'category_name' => 'gallery'
   );

   $q = new WP_Query($args);
   while ($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();
     $iPostID = $post->ID;
     $arrImages =& get_children('post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&post_parent=' . $iPostID );
     if($arrImages) {
       $arrKeys = array_keys($arrImages);
       $iNum = $arrKeys[0];
       $sThumbUrl = wp_get_attachment_thumb_url($iNum);
       $sImgString = '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' .
                       '<img src="' . $sThumbUrl . '" width="150" height="150" alt="Thumbnail Image" title="Thumbnail Image" />' .
                   '</a>';
       echo $sImgString;
     }

   endwhile;
   ```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You must try using nextgen gallery: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/